# Use Access filter with own keyword search together

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new in access and vba. Now I have a problem with my first project. I have created a table and a form with a keyword search. My Keyword search works fine but if i use also the standard filter from access together, i only can use the filter from one column because all other filter values are not available. I have make an msgbox to see the Output and access puts me an underscore before the table name.

```
Public Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim sql As String

sqlQuery = " brands.name LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
         & " OR brands.ID LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " 

sql = "SELECT brands.* " _
    & " FROM brands " _
    & " WHERE " & sqlQuery

Me.sfrmBrands.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

and the output

```
MsgBox (Me.sfrmBrands.Form.Filter)
```

Output: `([_brands].[name]="Test")`

But i need `([brands].[name]="Test")`

Comment: @Gustav is correct. Flagging this question as off-topic because of a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

It should read:

```
sqlQuery = " brands.name LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " & _
           " OR brands.ID LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' "
```

Also, all you do is to set the RecordSource of the subform leaving its filter setting untouched, so your messagebox will just display this filter.

To set the filter:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim Filter As String

sql = "SELECT * FROM brands"
Filter = "[name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " & _
         "OR [ID] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" 

Me.sfrmBrands.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.Filter = Filter
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.FilterOn = True
```

*Edit*: Filter before filter:

```
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.RecordSource = sql
' and perhaps:
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this changes the problem is the same.

Comment: I can see that. Your syntax fooled me.

Comment: Now the keywords set the filter but i want to filter the table by my keywords and then i want to use the standard filter values

Comment: Then your original code will work. Requery is not needed, but perhaps you need to reactive the filter. See edit.

Comment: My subform source object is a query. the keyword search work but after keyword search i only can use the standart filter in one column, not in all. if i use a table as subform source object and search with keywords in other tables it works fine

Comment: It might work if you use a form in _datasheetview_ as your subform, having your current query as RecordSource.

Comment: i have a search form with a subform with sourceobject my query how can i use my query in a form with datasheetview ?

Comment: Create a form using the query as recordsource. Then use the form as subform on your main form.

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem.. before i use the keyword search all filter are available, after search only one :/

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem but i have not a solution for that.

if i search by keywords the

```
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.RecordSource = sql
```

changes the table name from the query name to the subform name

is there an other solution for

```
Me.sfrmBrands.Form.RecordSource = sql
```